# 289 dimm pair 2 failed memory test

Tags: memory

In my IBM System eServer x336 , when I boot up, the red LED lit up, and it shows this:
289 DIMM Pair 2 failed memory test
DIMM 05 is affected
DIMM 06 is affected

Not very sure what I am supposed to do to troubleshoot it.

It still boots into the Windows Server OS though.

Comment: With some problem history, we could probably help advise you. Did it just suddenly start doing this one day? Did someone make any hardware changes?

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the faulty memory module(s).

Answer (score 1):

It could also be a CPU issue where a pin(s) might not be connected properly.  I am only saying this because two DIMMS near each other are giving the same error.  Try reseating the CPU/CPUs.